# C# Equivalent to AppScripts UrlFetchApp?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a C# console app and am having trouble translating into C# the following appscript/javascript code.

```
  let body = {
                'client_id': clientId,
                'client_secret': clientSecret,
                'audience': 'https://api.mycompany.com/',
                'grant_type':'client_credentials'
             }; 

  let options = {
                  'method':'post',
                  'contentType':'application/json',
                  'payload': JSON.stringify(body)
                };

  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(token_url,options);
  let json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  token = json.access_token;
```

Could someone save me a mountain of time exploring the infinite ways this can be done in C# please?

Here's what I have so far.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var body = new
    {
        client_id = clientId,
        client_secret= clientSecret,
        audience= "https://api.mycompany.com/",
        grant_type="client_credentials"
    };

    var jsonBody = JsonSerializer.Serialize(body);

    try
    {
        var response = client.PostAsync(token_url, new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
    }
                
}
```

thank you

Comment: Code looks ok at first sight. Is it working, and if not how is it not working?

Comment: @stuartd I get this error: Unhandled exception. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by
its access permissions.